# Magento 2.3.3 mail not working

Tags: magento2, mail

After applying EmailMessageInterface_2.3.3_backward_compatibility_composer-2019-10-30-10-20-09.patch in Magento 2.3.3, getting below error in log files.

main.CRITICAL: Type Error occurred when creating object: Magento\Framework\Mail\EmailMessage, Argument 2 passed to Magento\Framework\Mail\EmailMessage::__construct() must be of the type array, null given, called in /var/www/html/m233/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php on line 116 [] []

Please advise

Answer (score 0):

this is a known core bug you can fix it with the following core patch.

**Patch:**

```
--- vendor/magento/framework/Mail/Template/TransportBuilder.php
+++ vendor/magento/framework/Mail/Template/TransportBuilder.php
@@ -377,6 +377,7 @@ protected function prepareMessage()
     {
         $template = $this->getTemplate();
         $content = $template->processTemplate();
+
         switch ($template->getType()) {
             case TemplateTypesInterface::TYPE_TEXT:
                 $part['type'] = MimeInterface::TYPE_TEXT;
@@ -391,7 +392,10 @@ protected function prepareMessage()
                     new Phrase('Unknown template type')
                 );
         }
+
+        /** @var \Magento\Framework\Mail\MimePartInterface $mimePart */
         $mimePart = $this->mimePartInterfaceFactory->create(['content' => $content]);
+        $this->messageData['encoding'] = $mimePart->getCharset();
         $this->messageData['body'] = $this->mimeMessageInterfaceFactory->create(
             ['parts' => [$mimePart]]
         );
@@ -400,6 +404,7 @@ protected function prepareMessage()
             (string)$template->getSubject(),
             ENT_QUOTES
         );
+
         $this->message = $this->emailMessageInterfaceFactory->create($this->messageData);

         return $this;

--- dev/tests/integration/testsuite/Magento/Customer/Controller/AccountTest.php
+++ dev/tests/integration/testsuite/Magento/Customer/Controller/AccountTest.php
@@ -769,7 +769,19 @@ public function testConfirmationEmailWithSpecialCharacters(): void
         $message = $this->transportBuilderMock->getSentMessage();
         $rawMessage = $message->getRawMessage();

-        $this->assertContains('To: John Smith <' . $email . '>', $rawMessage);
+        /** @var \Zend\Mime\Part $messageBodyPart */
+        $messageBodyParts = $message->getBody()->getParts();
+        $messageBodyPart = reset($messageBodyParts);
+        $messageEncoding = $messageBodyPart->getCharset();
+        $name = 'John Smith';
+
+        if (strtoupper($messageEncoding) !== 'ASCII') {
+            $name = \Zend\Mail\Header\HeaderWrap::mimeEncodeValue($name, $messageEncoding);
+        }
+
+        $nameEmail = sprintf('%s <%s>', $name, $email);
+
+        $this->assertContains('To: ' . $nameEmail, $rawMessage);

         $content = $message->getBody()->getParts()[0]->getRawContent();
         $confirmationUrl = $this->getConfirmationUrlFromMessageContent($content);

--- dev/tests/integration/testsuite/Magento/Customer/Controller/AccountTest.php
+++ dev/tests/integration/testsuite/Magento/Customer/Controller/AccountTest.php
@@ -783,7 +783,7 @@ public function testConfirmationEmailWithSpecialCharacters(): void

         $this->assertContains('To: ' . $nameEmail, $rawMessage);

-        $content = $message->getBody()->getParts()[0]->getRawContent();
+        $content = $messageBodyPart->getRawContent();
         $confirmationUrl = $this->getConfirmationUrlFromMessageContent($content);
         $this->setRequestInfo($confirmationUrl, 'confirm');
         $this->clearCookieMessagesList();
```

[How to apply Patches on Magento 2](https://medium.com/@LarsRoettig/how-to-apply-patches-on-magento-2-b4fd83537f61)

**Isusses:**

1. https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/24902
2. https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/25542

Best regards,

Lars