# Magento 2.3.3 not sending any mails

Tags: email, cron, mail

My Magento 2.3.3 is not sending any emails from the solution.

As far as I can see, the cron job is running, the mail settings looks fine and are enabled.

I think I have tried it all, but no luck, it keeps saying "The order confirmation email is not sent".

I have tested if I can send a mail from a PHP file, and that works just fine.

Do anyone, have an idea?

Comment: Have you got any mail based extensions like attachments installed? 2.3.3 introduced some compatibility issues which were fixed in later versions

Comment: I had the Fooman_EmailAttachments it's as far as I know, the only one.

Had meaning I disabled it, but it didn't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Potentially the mail extension combined with a compatibility issue on 2.3.3 has broken it

[Magento 2.3.3 mail not working](https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/298388/70343)

https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-DevBlog/Backward-incompatible-Changes-in-the-Mail-Library-for-Magento-2/ba-p/144787

https://magento.com/tech-resources/download#download2333

Try the official patch (last link) first. The first two links are for information. The first one demonstrates the type of messages you should be seeing in the exception log. The second post details what went wrong.

Just directly apply patch. Cant use composer.

[EmailMessageInterface backward compatibility issue patch for Magento 2.3.3](https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/294379/70343)

Comment: Ok, thank you, will read trough the links and get back to you.

Comment: I had some problems installing the patch, so I ended up upgrading to 2.3.4 and now it works.

Thank you for the info!